# explicitly said that class implements interface

Tags: java

What is the real reason that in Java, and similar languages, must be explicitly said that a class implements an interface?

Imagine implicit implementation:

```
interface Flyer { void fly(); }

public class Duck { public void fly() {...} }

public class Plane { public void fly() {...} }

public class Hoe { void hangAround() {...} }

void startFlying(Flyer flyer) {...}

void race() {
    ...
    startFlying(duck);  // OK
    startFlying(plane); // OK
    startFlying(hoe);   // Compilation error.
}
```

Compiler knows method's signatures, return type (and modifier, of course). At this point it seems clear that there is no need to explicitly specify that Duck and Plane implements Flyer.

I would said that "implements XYZ" may be removed from Java without worries.

No difference, check at compilation time so it's OK.

In the other hand:
@JBNizet mentioned different meaning of methods with the same signature and return type.

I will use his example:

```
interface Runner { void run(); }

public class Guy { public void run(); }
public class Gal { public void run(); }

void startRunning(Runner r) {...}

void race() {
    startRunning(guy);            // OK
    startRunning(gal);            // OK
    startRunning(runnableThread); // OK
}
```

OK for compiler, OK for startRunning() (OK for me). It's up to your philosophy if this is OK for you or not.

Explicit:

```
public class Guy **implements Runner **{ public void run(); }
public class Gal **implements Runner **{ public void run(); }
```

In bold (or text between ** and **) is the price which you must pay for

```
void race() {
    startRunning(guy);            // OK
    startRunning(gal);            // OK
    startRunning(runnableThread); // Compilation error!
}
```

Note compilation error so you can see the issue before testing.

If it's intended to use runnableThread in startRunning() as well you must do it even more explicitly (enough time to realize what you are doing).

"I wondered how much of time is wasted by resolving issues related to typing "implements XYZ" compared to time wasted by resolving issues with implicitly implemented interfaces. If it's way more better for implicitly implemented interface then I hate Java designers for their decision and that they force us to belive it's better :-)"

---

Ladybug and airbus (and duck)

I think the issue with implicitly implemented interface is only theoretical and rare in real.

```
public class Airbus {
    void takeOff() {...}
    void land() {...}
    Passenger[] getPassengers() {...}
}

public class Ladybug {
    void takeOff() {...}
    void land() {...}
}
public class Duck {
    void takeOff() {...}
    void land() {...}
    Passenger[] getPassengers() {...}
}

public interface Aircraft {
    void takeOff();
    void land();
    Passenger[] getPassengers();
}

public void fly(Aircraft aircraft) {
    aircraft.takeOff();
    for (Passenger p : aircraft.getPassengers()) {...}
    aircraft.land();
}

public void airport() {
    fly(airbus_a380); // OK
    fly(ladybug);     // Compilation error, does not match Aircraft requirements.
    fly(duck);        // OK
}

public interface Lander {
    void land();
}

public void landAtMeadow(Lander lander) {...}

public void meadow() {
    landAtMeadow(airbus_a380); // OK
    landAtMeadow(duck);        // OK
    landAtMeadow(ladybug);     // OK
}
```

All of them are matching requirements of landAtMeadow so they can be used in that context. Even it may not be possible to land at meadow for airbus_a380 (In other word testing is required) you need to land there in emergency.

Do not forget that landAtMeadow() may have more specific requirements like

```
public interface Lander { void landAtLimitedArea(int size); }
```

to say that the space is limited, so if airbus_a380 does not support this method then you have compilation error here.

Comment: A Duck can fly, a Plane can fly too. But in an airport management program, you don't want to use ducks instead of planes. Type safety allows avoiding these kinds of errors, at the cost of less flexibility. Duck-typing has its use and is often more flexible, but at the cost of reduced robustness and harder to find errors.

Comment: Wiki link to [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: Not a big deal to type few words, but as you can see it's not really needed. Both, explicit and implicit way, are checked for error at compilation time. There are more differences between duck and plane.

Comment: That's the problem: it's obviously an error to pass a duck to a method expecting a plane. But with duck typing, if the method only calls fly() on its argument, everything will compile fine, instead of detecting the error at compile-time.

Comment: @JBNizet If duck implements fly() and plane implements fly() then they are the same from point of view of method what needs only "fly()". If some method requires stewardessServices() and duck does not implements it then it's compilation error.

Comment: Can't imagine the debugging hell we'd be in if Java was duck-typed!

Comment: @MartinDrlík, not necessarily compilation error, this may turn out at runtime and the program is dead then. And if at runtime code expects something declared as implementing X and you pass something different it refuses to use it, instead of checking if all the necessary methods are there. I tried to describe it in my answer.

Comment: Martin, if both duck and plane should be used in a place where only fly() is needed, they should both implement an interface which specifies that and only that -- FlyingObject, perhaps. The only way to ensure that you don't try to book a duck to take you from Boston to Oslo is to know that ducks are NOT planes, and that's what strong typing gives us.

Comment: @MartinDrlík: that's the definition of duck typing. It allows to pass a duck to a method that is intended to take a plane as argument (which is, most of the time, an error that will probably be detected, later, and at runtime). Java, being strongly typed, detects that you're passing a duck to a method expecting a plane at compile-time. There is nothing inherently wrong with duck typing, but it has serious disadvantages over strong typing, especially for large software.

Comment: By the way, if you really want to reference objects via duck-typing in Java -- if you really just want to use the fly method without worrying about the object type -- you can do that via reflection. It's a bad idea, but you can do it.

Comment: @JBNizet but this is not duck typing. This is about passing something which has method "fly()" for instance. It does not matter if it's implemented by duck or plane. If it's intended to pass instance of Plane so you would rather use method(Plane p), right? Or something which implements methods what you need.

Comment: The problem is that, with your way of doing, you have absolutely no idea if Plane.fly() is implemented in order to fulfill the contract of Fly.fly(), or if, by accident, Plane has a method with the same signature as Fly.fly(), but which does something completely unrelated. Let's say you implement an athletics game, with a Runner interface containing a run() method. It wouldn't be a good idea to pass any Thread or Runnable implementation to this method, because run() has not the same meaning for a Thread or Runnable as it has for a Runner.

Comment: @JBNizet In any case there will be probably more methods in Runner for athletics games than just "void run()" so the probability to match the same signatures in unrelevant classes is lowered. In theory I must agree, but practically it's extra typing just for sweet compilation error in really rarely cases.

Comment: Better yet, consider an InsectFarm with a getter called `fly()` that returns a Fly. Should you be able to use an InsectFarm as an Airplane?

Comment: @yshavit If some method requires interface then it does not require instance of InsectFarm or Airplane, it requires instance of anything which implements this interface. "Fly fly()" and "void fly()" is not the same. "void fly()" of Airplane and "void fly()" of InsectFarm, match requirements of one who needs "void fly()". I can't imagine a real case where you have imported packages one for InsectFarm and another for Airplane.

Comment: Of course `Fly fly()` and `void fly()` aren't the same -- but the statement `fly();` can refer to either one. The point that others were making is that by doing this kind of duck typing, you take away the ability to have the compiler do basic sanity checks for you. I was just pointing out that those sanity checks don't even have to be of the sort of "one flying thing vs another," but could in fact be for _completely_ unrelated classes.

Comment: How bad developer you are if you created several classes with the same methods and used them where it is possible to accidently pass it in totally inappropriate context? Go through your code and find a situation where you can accidentally pass unrelevant class which match interface's requirement. I am pretty sure there is no such a case, or very rare.

Comment: Better point: each class has "String toString()" right? Imagine "interface ToString { String toString(); }" is there a case, with implicit implementation, where is method "String toString()" totally irrelevant in context of "interface ToString { String toString(); }"?

Answer (score 5):

Java is a strong typed language, so the assignation of an instance to an interface typed variable must be validated at compile time. This can only be done by explicitly declared interface implementations.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this is a basic characteristic of the Java language. It's there for good reasons, folks who are doing serious largescale programming like it, and there's absolutely no reason to change it.

If it bothers you, I strongly recommend that you find another language that is more weakly typed and use that instead. There are a fair number of languages these days which can be compiled into Java bytecodes and used in a Java environment, so you might not even have to give up the flexibility of being able to run in a JVM.

Comment: Please specify how this makes Java less strongly typed.

Comment: Two classes with the same signature may not be intended to be implementations of the same interface. Requiring the assertion permits distinguishing whether they are appropriate for use in a given context or not. Your approach does not provide that information. 

Strong typing is as much about excluding inappropriate actions as facilitating appropriate ones. Read the discussion of duck typing referenced above, and/or websearch that phrase for past discussion of where it might or might not be appropriate.

Comment: In any case, Java is Java, and the odds of it accepting this basic a change are absolutely zero. Either resign yourself to using it as it is designed to work, or find or write your own language.

Answer (score 0):

My friend In a strongly typed languages, for ex: in C or Java, when a variable or reference is declared, it must be informed to the compiler what data type the variable or reference is of

Answer (score 0):

When a class is declared to implement an interface X then any other method working with interface X **is sure that all the necessary methods are implemented in the class** (and therefore they do not need to check every time if needed method is implemented). If there was no such declaration, then any method using classes which implement X would need to:

- ensure that the class of object whith which the method is working implements all methods necessary (so go through all the methods of the class searching the ones you want every time you expect to work with interface X - instead of doing this once, at compilation).
- have many error handling lines of code implemented (what to do, if I expect method A to do something, but method A it is not there at all?)

Static typing adds much to code's safety in general, as many errors are possible to detect at compilation. Why try to change Java from staticaly to dynamicaly typed? There are many dynamicaly typed languages out there, with their pluses and minuses, ready to use (Python, for example).